# Updating child rows based on parent values with Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, parent-child, hierarchy

I have 2 tables in Oracle with structures similar to these:

**family** table

```
id member parent_id  flag flight
---------------------------------
1   A     null       N    null
2   B      1         N    null
3   C     null       N    null
4   D      3         N    null
5   E      3         N    null
6   F     null       N    null
7   G      6         N    null
```

**flight** table

```
id   family_id   flight
-----------------------

1      1         1000
2      3         2000
```

Here rows with id  4,5 in family table are child of Row 3 and Row 2 is child of 1.

Now, I need to write a oracle update sql to not only update the corresponding parent row with flight and change the flag to Y but child rows also should be updated accordingly. If there is no corresponding flight assignment for family in flight table then rows 6,7 should remain as such.

Doing parent update and finding child for a parent easy. But is it possible to do all updates in one sql?

Thanks.

**Update**

```
update family fm set (flag, flight) = 
(
  select 'Y', fl.flight  from flight fl where fm.flag <> 'Y' and
(
  (fl.parent_id=fm.id and fm.parent_id is null )
 or fm.parent_id=fl.parent_id
)
)
where exists (select 1 from flight fl where fm.id=fl.parent_id or fl.parent_id=fm.parent_id );
```

This works !!

Comment: Post the "*easy*" part here.

Comment: You can't update multiple tables with a single UPDATE statement.

Comment: I am not looking into updating multiple tables. Only family table needs to be updated but the update has to cascade to child rows also along with parent row. How can I modify this sql to do a cascade also:                                                          UPDATE family fm SET (fm.flight, flag) = 
  (SELECT  fl.flight, "Y" FROM  flight fl WHERE fl.family_id = fm.id ) 
  WHERE EXISTS 
  (  SELECT 1 FROM flight fl  WHERE fl.family_id = fm.id and fm.flag <> "Y" and fm.flight IS NULL)

Comment: Try searching `connect by prior` online, you should have your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can .In oracle , it is easy to select recursively.Here is my suggestion :

```
Update family set flag='Y' 
    where id in(select id from family start with id=3 
                     connect by prior id=parent_id)
```

Comment: But how do I do it for all families not a particular family i.e how do I have start with to work for all families?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to update in Oracle all the families,not just a particular one, could be this:

```
update family F
set flag='Y', 
FLIGHT=(
SELECT FLIGHT FROM FLIGHT WHERE FAMILY_ID=F.PARENT_ID OR f.id=family_id
)
WHERE ID IN (select id 
from family a 
start with id in (
select family_id from flight where a.id=family_id)
                     connect by prior id=parent_id);
```

Hope it helps.